# jQuery hover and fadeTo effect is slow in IE 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, hover, fadeto

I've been developing my website in both Firefox and IE 8.  There's an image hover effect on the main page (as well as in the photography and drawing sections).  You can see the code in the source at http://www.dgendill.com.  In Firefox, the effect works perfect.  In IE 8, it works, but it's much, much slower.  Here's what I've tried to improve the speed:

1. Used the optimized jQuery library
2. Narrowed the scope with which jQuery traverses the DOM.  For instance:

   ```
   $(".sectionLink","#divLandingPage").hover(
       function(){
           $(this).addClass("hover");
           $(this).fadeTo(100,.8);
       },
       function(){
           $(this).removeClass("hover");
           $(this).fadeTo(100,.99);
       }
   );
   ```
3. I've tried changing the display type of the image.  Display block, inline-block, and inline.

Any ideas why IE 8 is so much slower?  My HTML is valid 4.01.

Here's a guy that's worked with the same problem:
http://mdasblog.wordpress.com/2009/07/24/jquery-fun-with-animation-and-opacity/

I've decided to just disable the hover effect in IE.

```
if(jQuery.support.opacity) {
    $(".sectionLink","#divLandingPage").hover(
        function(){
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $(this).fadeTo(100,.8);
    },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            $(this).fadeTo(100,.99);
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's the solution, but you don't need to create a window.load event. Everything you are doing in that event could be done in the document.ready event.

Comment: Side question:  Does document.load activate when all the images have completed loading?  It seems like I can only get that to work when I used window.load.

Comment: Found the difference: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/  Thanks for the tip, I'll switch to either one or the other

Comment: IE8 and below have terrible JS performance, along with the fact that jQuery has to do a bit more work to get opacity to work. This means your animations end up slow and jumpy. Unfortunately there's no real way around that

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".sectionLink img").hover(function(){ 
        $(this).addClass("hover").fadeTo(100,.8);
    }, function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass("hover").fadeTo(100,.99); 
    });
```

You could try to attach the eventhandler direct on to the image, or if this doesnt help, try the animate method. 
A possible reason may be that IE doesnt support opacity as a css property.

You should chain the code btw.

The load() event triggers when the content is downloaded and rendered. 
The ready() event triggers when the document is ready to be worked on/manipulated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  You're right, it does look like an opacity problem.  I've decided to disable the hover effect in IE.  I'll probably implement a CSS only hover effect in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that jQuery's animation effects have issues in all versions of IE when an element has a CSS `position` attribute applied to it. Typically wrapping the element in a div without a `position` attribute applied will fix the issue. More information can be found [in jQuery slideToggle and Internet Explorer](http://www.ndoherty.biz/2007/09/jquery-slidetoggle-and-internet-explorer/).